# How can I write a regex to match a torrents title format?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to match and break up a typical tv torrent's title:

> MyTV.Show.S09E01.HDTV.XviD
>   MyTV.Show.S10E02.HDTV.XviD
>   MyTV.Show.901.HDTV.XviD
>   MyTV.Show.1102.HDTV.XviD

I'm trying to break these strings up into 3 capture groups for each entry: Title, Season, Episode.

I can handle the first 2 easy enough:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9.]*)\.S([0-9]{1,2})E([0-9]{1,2}).*$
```

However, the third and fourth one prove difficult to break apart the season and episode.  If I could work backwards it would be easier.  For example, with "901", If I could work backwards it would be take the first to digits as the episode number, anything remaining before that is the season number.

Does anyone have any tips for how I can break these strings up into those relevant capture groups?

Comment: This is ambiguous. Do I interpret `102` as `S1E02` or `S10E2`?

Comment: @Null This is a very valid point, which is why in my answer I brought up the fact that I've never seen a torrent released with a single digit for its episode number.  I think for the sake of sanity checking everything, it's safe enough to assume that `102` is S01E02.

Comment: What if we assume that it is in the number only format, that the last 2 digits are episode and the first digit is the season?

Comment: Check out my update on my answer, or the end of my previous comment.  I think the easiest way to get a high enough rate of success is to assume that the episode is 2 digits.  It won't cover every case, but it should do a good enough job without making the problem really complicated.

Answer (score 15):

Here's what I would use:

```
(.*?)\.S?(\d{1,2})E?(\d{2})\.(.*)
```

Has capture groups:

```
1: Name
2: Season
3: Episode
4: The Rest
```

---

Here's some code in C# (courtesy of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793387/a-way-to-use-regex-to-find-a-set-of-filenames-paths-in-a-string/3793456#3793456)): [see it live](http://ideone.com/pgsFp)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        string s = @"MyTV.Show.S09E01.HDTV.XviD
            MyTV.Show.S10E02.HDTV.XviD
            MyTV.Show.901.HDTV.XviD
            MyTV.Show.1102.HDTV.XviD";

        Extract(s);

    }

    private static readonly Regex rx = new Regex
        (@"(.*?)\.S?(\d{1,2})E?(\d{2})\.(.*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    static void Extract(string text)
    {
        MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(text);

        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Season: {1}, Ep: {2}, Stuff: {3}\n",
                match.Groups[1].ToString().Trim(), match.Groups[2], 
                match.Groups[3], match.Groups[4].ToString().Trim());
        }
    }

}
```

Produces:

```
Name: MyTV.Show, Season: 09, Ep: 01, Stuff: HDTV.XviD
Name: MyTV.Show, Season: 10, Ep: 02, Stuff: HDTV.XviD
Name: MyTV.Show, Season: 9, Ep: 01, Stuff: HDTV.XviD
Name: MyTV.Show, Season: 11, Ep: 02, Stuff: HDTV.XviD
```

Comment: Interesting, I would of thought that (\d{1,2}) would of greedily tried to match 2 digits, since technically 2 were available.

Comment: @KingNestor It won't because then it would fail to match the `\d{2}` that comes after it.

Comment: So, in its process of matching, does it first attempt to match 2 and then backtrack later to try matching 1?

Comment: This fails to properly match shows that have a number in their title, like Castle.2009.S06E02.HDTV.x264-LOL.mp4

Comment: +1 for compilable code. Always helpful to see a copy & paste example

Answer (score 2):

Almost every media file I've ever seen that has come from a torrent had two-digit episodes.  With that, you should be able to do `E([0-9]{2}).` instead and get the expression to match.

I'd estimate 99.9% of shows are marked with two digit episodes.  If you're trying to write a script to easily label your own shows, I'd go with the two digit episode assumption and manually rename mistagged files you come across.  If you're trying to write something for public consumption, you probably have a *lot* more syntaxes that you'll need to consider.  I've seen this tried by other applications in the past, and all have worked just so-so.  It's a hard problem that probably has no single solution.

Comment: your regex sample that you posted is addressing the portion that I have no problem with.  When the letters 'S' and 'E' are present, I have no troubles.  I'm looking for help with the format when they aren't there.

Comment: @King - Sorry - I had been editing my post to more accurately address your concerns, probably when you were already commenting.  Does my update help any further?